# Single Grails application accessed through multiple domains

Tags: apache, tomcat, grails, tomcat7, grails-3.0

I have a Grails application that will be accessed through multiple web domains depending on the `id` of a domain class.

The application has an admin area (`/`) and then it can have multiple organizations, and each organization would access a part of the application using a custom domain.

[image: Design]

The idea is having a domain class `Organization`, and every time a new instance is created a new "website" would be accessible through the path `/organization/show/<id>`. Later, a new domain (.com, .org, ...) would be registered and added to the Apache mod proxy configuration as a new virtual host.

Would this approach work? How could I handle absolute links (css, images, js, fonts, ...) generated by Grails tags?

I'm using Grails 3.28, Groovy 2.4.10, JVM 1.8.0_121, Apache HTTPD Server, Apache Tomcat 7 and a Linux server.